# Minimum value of $|z|+|z-1|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How do we prove that for any complex number $z$ the minimum value of $|z|+|z-1|$ is $1$ ?
$$
|z|+|z-1|=|z|+|-(z-1)|\geq|z-(z-1)|=|z-z+1|=|1|=1\\\implies|z|+|z-1|\geq1
$$

But, when I do as follows
$$
|z|+|z-1|\geq|z+z-1|=|2z-1|\geq2|z|-|1|\geq-|1|=-1
$$
Since LHS can never be less than 0, $|z|+|z-1|\geq0$

Why do I seem to get different result compared to the first method ?

ie.
1st method $\implies (|z|+|z-1|)_{min}=1\\$

2nd method$\implies (|z|+|z-1|)_{min}=0\\$

What is going wrong in the second approach ?

Comment: Think about geometry of the complex plane.

Comment: @Vim thnx. but i dont get what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder $z$ is any complex number.

Comment: What you got is also true. $|z|+|z-1|$ must be $\ge0$ for every $z$. There is, however, no guarantee that the equality case can be reached.

Comment: @ss1729: Just because one method yields a weaker result, doesn't make it wrong. It just makes it not useful.

Comment: Your second approach is not wrong, though it is not informative. $|z|+|z-1|\ge -1$ does not mean that $|z|+|z-1|$ can be less than zero.

Comment: @choco_addicted thanx. Since the second approach gives $|z|+|z-1|\geq{-1}$ and we know it can never be $\leq{0}$. So it just merely says LHS is greater than or equal to $-1$ but the information is not precise, do not contain anything about the min value. s that right ?

Comment: @ss1729 Absolutely right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangle inequality tells you that
$$
|z|+|z-1|=|z|+|1-z|\ge|z+1-z|=1
$$
which is what you did. Taking into account that for $z=1/2$ you have equality, the minimum is $1$.

The other approach simply gives you a different lower bound, which is not very informative:
$$
|z|+|z-1|\ge|z+z-1|=|2z-1|\ge0
$$
is already known.

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality:
$$|z|+|z-1|\ge |z-(z-1)|=1$$
And $1$ is attained when $z=0$, say.

Comment: I think you must read the complete question of OP.He isn't asking what you have answered.

Comment: @JaideepKhare he asks to prove $\ge1$, he got $\ge0$ which *is* right but we aren't interested.

Comment: @Vim i'm asking about the minimum value of $|z|+|z-1|$. I hv edited my original post. pls check

Comment: @ss1729 my answer says exactly the $\inf$ is $1$. Note that your second approach didn't get the inf (greatest lower bound) but simply a lower bound.

Comment: @Vim thanx. I think i got it.

Answer (score 0):

$$|z|+|1-z|\geq|z+1-z|=1$$
The equality occurs for $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: could u pls comment on the second method, which seems to suggest the min. value of $|z|+|z-1|$ is $0$.

Comment: @ss1729 The equality occurs for all real $z$ such that $0\leq z\leq1$.